# Is it safe to access the same file by several FileInputStream?

Tags: java, multithreading, fileinputstream

As described in the title, I would like to open several FileInputStream object to access the same file to obtain data in different position. Is it safe to do that, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is perfectly fine as long as all you're doing is reading, and none of your threads/streams puts an exclusive lock on the file.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, technically this is just concurrent reading of a file from the OS standpoint, and since it is not modified under your feet, you are good to go.

Comment: Just don't forget to make sure you close all the input streams once you are done reading to avoid resource leakage (file handles).